# How do I better stylize a ListBox of images in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've binded a List from my code-behind to a ListBox but I'm having difficulty stylizing the look to get what I want. I'd like to show up to 8 images at once, but no more than that without scrolling down. When the window resizes, I would like the image sizes to scale with it but still have no more than 8 showing. Here's my current XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PictureImagesList}">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Here's a pic of what this XAML produces. As you can see the images are much too large and we only see the top half of the second row. If I mess around with ListBoxItem margin I can get them smaller but this isn't really ideal as it only works if the screen resolution stays the same.

[image: I'm Getting This]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a UniformGrid as ItemsPanel with appropriate `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`. Also remove the redundant Border element from the DataTemplate.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PictureImagesList}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="200" Height="200" Margin="5" Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Update: In order to have the yellow selection border directly around the image, use a ListBoxItem Style like shown below. To have the images scaled to (a fraction of) the full ListBox width, add an appropriate ControlTemplate.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PictureImagesList}">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    BorderThickness="5"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This sort of works like I want it to. Is there a way to get the selection to just be around the image instead of the entire 200x200 frame? Also, is there any way for the size of each image frame to be determined dynamically instead of having to specify 200x200?

Comment: @alduin See the update for how to get the selection frame directly around the image. Not sure what you mean with setting *the size of each frame dynamically*. If each image should have an individual size, bind the ListBox to a collection of data items with an ImageSource (or an image path) property and properties for the images size. Then bind the Width and Height of the Grid in the ControlTemplate to these properties.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. By setting the size of each frame dynamically I just mean kind of like how a grid is made by setting the column and row definitions with "*". By frame I'm just referring to the area which each image scales to fit. Basically I was hoping to get my ListBox display to scale dynamically as the main window changes size.

Comment: Well, that's simple. Just add an appropriate ControlTemplate. See the edited question. Also remove the explicit Width and Height from the ListBoxItemStyle.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not being clear before. I could see it in my head, I was just having trouble putting it into words.

Comment: Updated my post description and code again. I think I'm almost there. Just need to figure out how to make the default image sizes smaller and maintain the dynamic scaling when the window resizes or the screen resolution is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Set your image dimensions to be the same and use a WrapPanel instead:

```
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="5" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform" Width="400" Height="400"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Alternatively, if you want a fixed number of columns then don't specify image dimensions at all and instead use a UniformGrid:

```
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="5" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

UPDATE: I'm at a bit of a loss now to understand exactly what it is you're trying to do, the images you're posting don't match your description. If you want the panels to be square, and the images to scale up to them uniformly with a thin border around them, then there are a few things you'll have to do:

1) change your ListBoxItem ControlTemplate to be a Border with a Transparent background and the ContentPresenter inside it. This will ensure that your yellow border doesn't fill the whole box, and that the rest of the box doesn't highlight when selected, but that you can still click anywhere on it to select it.

2) change your ItemTemplate to be a grid (so that it fills all available space) with a border centered in the middle of it with padding (so that you'll be able to see the yellow border when selected), then put your Image content inside that but wrap.

This should do the job:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="PictureListBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Border Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                <Border Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter  />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If that still isn't it then you'll need to define your requirements more clearly.

Comment: Damn, Clemens always has a habit of posting answers as I'm writing my own! :)

Comment: Yeah, but he's explicitly specifying different x/y Image dimensions, which is what's causing the large borders. Both will work, just depends on whether he's after fixed columns or not.

Comment: Did you try with UniformGrid without setting the ItemsPresenter size? It shows the images in full size.

Comment: The UniformGrid option got me a bit closer but I'm still having trouble getting everything to the right size and spacing. I updated my original post with the latest code and images of what it produces.

Comment: @alduin if you want square panels then set your image Width and Height to both be the same.

Comment: Is there a way to set it dynamically so it's based on a percentage of a grid? Much like how rows and columns are defined when creating a grid. I've updated the code and images again. Getting much closer!